# creating a new model instance/record with associated foreign keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm new to Sequelize and am having some syntax issues. I've made the following models:

```
// User
sequelize.define('user', {
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
});

// Type
sequelize.define('type', {
  typeName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
});
```

I created an association between them:

```
User.Type = User.belongsTo(Type, { foreignKey: { allowNull: false } })
```

And confirmed that the resulting User table has a foreign key reference to `typeId`.

When I want to create a new user, I want to also pass in a string of 'fan' or 'band' that would be a reference to one of the two types that populate the Type table. How do I communicate that in my `create` function?

```
const createUser = (req, res) => {
    const { name, type } = req.body;
    User.create({
        name,
        include: [{
            association: User.Type
        }]
    })
    .then(() => console.log('success'))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: Side note unrelated to your problem: you're mixing promises and callbacks. Use one or the other. You can use promises in express with https://github.com/express-promise-router/express-promise-router

Comment: Changed, thanks for the pointer!

Comment: And _then_ don't forget to use async/await or at least always return your promises ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a user and type with associations. Below example using `"sequelize": "^5.21.3"`

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
import { DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import { sequelize } from '../../db';

export const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
});

export const Type = sequelize.define('type', {
  typeName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
});

User.Type = User.belongsTo(Type, { foreignKey: { allowNull: false } });

export const createUser = (req, res) => {
  const { name, type } = req.body;
  return User.create(
    {
      name,
      type: { typeName: type },
    },
    { include: [{ association: User.Type }] },
  )
    .then(() => console.log('success'))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
import { createUser, Type, User } from './';
import { sequelize } from '../../db';

describe('59849396', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
  });
  afterAll(async () => {
    await sequelize.close();
  });
  it('should create user with type correctly', async () => {
    const mReq = { body: { name: 'Tom', type: 'band' } };
    const mRes = {};
    await createUser(mReq, mRes);
    const type = await Type.findOne({ where: { typeName: 'band' } });
    const user = await User.findOne({ where: { name: 'Tom' } });
    expect(type.typeName).toBe(mReq.body.type);
    expect(user.typeId).toBe(type.id);
  });
});
```

Test results:

```sh
 PASS  src/examples/stackoverflow/59849396/index.test.js
  59849396
    ✓ should create user with type correctly (74ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.253s, estimated 4s
```

After running the test, check the database.

```sh
node-sequelize-examples=# select * from users;
 id | name |         createdAt          |         updatedAt          | typeId 
----+------+----------------------------+----------------------------+--------
  1 | Tom  | 2020-01-22 07:12:05.447+00 | 2020-01-22 07:12:05.447+00 |      1
(1 row)

node-sequelize-examples=# select * from types;
 id | typeName |         createdAt         |         updatedAt         
----+----------+---------------------------+---------------------------
  1 | band     | 2020-01-22 07:12:05.45+00 | 2020-01-22 07:12:05.45+00
(1 row)
```

As you can see, we also create the "band" `type` when creating the user "Tom". Which means `types` table is populated with a data row as well.